# Using Unbounds stub-zone and NSD for local resolving does not work

Tags: networking, dns, unbound

I am having issues setting up `Unbound` as a general use DNS resolver and `NSD` as a local authoritive server. I intend to use `Unbound` as a replacement for my routers `DNS` server and would like to incorporate a range of private domains which may reference each other.

Using Unbounds local DNS resolver via `local-data` and alike does not fulfill my needs; hence the need for NSD.

My setup is that I have Unbound running on Port `53` and NSD on Port `10053` (listening only on localhost) on the same machine.

My Unbound config:

```
server:
      # private and link-local subnets
      private-address: 10.0.0.0/8
      private-address: 172.16.0.0/12
      private-address: 192.168.0.0/16
      private-address: 169.254.0.0/16
      private-address: fd00::/8
      private-address: fe80::/10

      local-zone: "xe." transparent
      private-domain: "xe"

stub-zone:
      name: "xe"
      stub-addr: ::1@10053
      stub-addr: 127.0.0.1@10053
```

I won't go into details of my zone config for `xe.` but I can tell you that using `dig -p 10053 <domain>.xe` resolves just fine.
Unbound resolves external domains like `google.com` without any problems.

I just cannot seem to get this to work. Do you have any suggestions on how I might get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

So ... in this case the solution was to set `do-not-query-localhost: no` and define `domain-insecure: "xe"`. `local-zone: "xe." transparent` was removed.